# Azure App to Azure Database "Connection Failed" with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, azure

I have a C# .Net **Web API** deployed to an **Azure App Service**, I also have an **Azure SQL Database**.

In the API I am using Entity Framework to insert into the database, but I keep getting the error message: "**The underlying provider failed on open**".

(When running the API locally (in debug mode) connecting to a local database it works fine).
Could this be a permissions/firewall configuration problem with the Azure database, or something else?

I have added my current IP address in the "Azure Set Server Firewall", do I need to add the Azure Web API's IP address to the database firewall settings?

This is my API:

```
public class ProfileController : ApiController
{
    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [WebMethod]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostProfile([FromBody] Profile details)
    {
        var context = new XXXDBEntities();
        var query = from c in context.Users
                    where c.Email.Equals(details.email, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                    select c;
        var emailFound = query.Count();


        if (emailFound != 0)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "There is already an account associated with this email address");
        }
        else
        {
            Guid token = Guid.NewGuid();
            Users newRow = new Users();
            newRow.Token = token;
            newRow.FirstName = details.firstName;
            newRow.LastName = details.lastName;
            newRow.Email = details.email;
            newRow.Password = details.password;
            context.Users.Add(newRow);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, token);
        }

    }
```

This is my connection string:
This is the default format for connection strings in .Net Entity Framework, I have only added username, password and changed the data source and catalog fields. Is this correct?

```
<add name="XXXDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/XXXDB.csdl|res://*/XXXDB.ssdl|res://*/XXXDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:XXX.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=XXXDB;integrated security=True;User ID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Are you able to run locally but still connect successfully to your Azure SQL instance?

Comment: Why do you have `integrated security=True` in the connection string when you specify a username and password?

Comment: Thanks! I removed the "integrated security= true" and added "persist security info=True". It now connects successfully :)

Comment: @juunas you should have posted this as the answer so Tess could mark the question as having been answered

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your connection string, it seems to be right. So I think your issue may be caused by the model of the SQL Azure is changed, but your project does not update it. Here is the same issue I reproduced on my side:

[image]

I would suggest you update your model.

> do I need to add the Azure Web API's IP address to the database firewall settings?

We can set Allow access to Azure services as **ON** in SQL Azure firewall settings. So that we need not to add Azure web API's address.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I already set it to true, thanks. It was changing the connection string which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `Integrated Security=True` from the connection string since you are specifying a username and password.